# Removing trailing .0 in few values of column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table `ABC` and column `A` where few values have `.0` and I want to remove the `.0` in all those values. Also a few values are string values in this column so am unable to use `trunc` on the values. So please let me know how I can do this in `oracle 10g` or `11g`.

Comment: if you are using oracle .. why  your qiestion is tagged mysql  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

A few oldfashioned functions (such as SUBSTR & TRIM, if it is necessary) might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2.0'    from dual union
  3     select '3.20'   from dual union
  4     select '150.02' from dual union
  5     select 'ABAC.0' from dual union
  6     select 'DEF'    from dual union
  7     select '12345'  from dual union
  8     select '12.0 '  from dual
  9    )
 10  select col,
 11    case when substr(trim(col), -2) = '.0' then substr(trim(col), 1, length(trim(col)) - 2)
 12         else col
 13    end col_new
 14  from test;

COL    COL_NE
------ ------
12.0   12
12345  12345
150.02 150.02
2.0    2
3.20   3.20
ABAC.0 ABAC
DEF    DEF

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `TRIM` with `TRAILING` option twice.
`where a like '%.0'` can also be used if u like.

```
UPDATE yourtable t
   SET a = TRIM (TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM (TRAILING '0' FROM a))
 WHERE SUBSTR (a, -2) = '.0';
```

Its is similar to  `RTRIM ( RTRIM(a, '0' ),'.')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below sql to correct your data:

```
UPDATE ABC S
   SET S.A = SUBSTR (S.A, 1, LENGTH (S.A) - 2)
 WHERE INSTR (SUBSTR (S.A, -2, 2), '.0', -1) = 1;
```